# Automatically detect unresponsive processes

Tags: process, monitoring

Every once in a while, a process becomes unresponsive for whatever reason. After noticing my laptop fan crying out loud I quickly find and kill the culprit in htop.

My question is: is there a graphical tool for detecting such events? Something similar to Android's "Force quit | Wait" dialog when an app is taking longer than usual.

I've searched for a bit but came up with nothing... maybe I wasn't using the right terms.

Thanks!

Comment: I know the Gnome desktop environment has a "Force quit | Wait" dialog, but it has a delay of, I think, 30 seconds before it shows up. I'm don't know if Unity in Ubuntu 11.04 has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use top in a terminal. I know it's not graphical and not automatic, but it has very low memory footprint.

- Open **gnome-terminal**
- Type **top**
- Press **P** to sort by CPU usage.
- When you see a process eating up all your CPU,
  press **K** and provide the process-id
  of the offending app.
- If the process is not running as your
  current user, for example: **root**, you
  will have to start top as root (be careful with that).

Comment: The OP already uses htop, which is a more colorful version of top.

Comment: As elmicha mentioned, I'm already using htop for this. I wanted something automatic and graphical, similar to what you find in Android phones.